# Android java using Eclipse math, I don't know why simple math is coming up with wrong result?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, math

I have four variables with the following values (I am sure about the values they have):

```
15
100
1
4000
```

I am trying to output the values into a toast message, but they are coming up wrong.

Here is what I did:

```
Toast.makeText( TreActivity.this,
                String.valueOf( ((15 + 100) * 10) + 4000 ),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
```

When testing this in the emulator, it comes up as `14150`.  This is
wrong, because ((15+100)*10)+4000 = 5150.

I must be missing something special with Android/Java in the way things are calculated.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If I copy your code exactly as you've written it into an activity, I get 5150 in my Toast message. It's more likely that you are mistaken about the content of your variables, regardless of how sure you are, then that math doesn't work right on Android.

Comment: That's not your actual code or you're doing something else in code that isn't posted here. There is no bug in `String.valueOf()` and it will output the result you expect.

Comment: What is the type of your variables?

Comment: Anyway, it seems that the second variable is 1000, not 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont do String.valueOf(...) just try your calculation and then at the end put +"" to make it a string. See what that does

UPDATE:

If the problem isnt fixed yet you should try breaking the equasion down to see where the issue is. you should add 100 and 15 together and just put 150 and then just keep doing that untill you see where the issue is. It might be that you have a parenthases out of place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and trying to help, but I got the same wrong result.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using valueOf(). ""+ is just a shortcut to the same behavior.

Comment: @GreatDreams - exactly, because the problem is that your values aren't what you think they are.

Comment: the values are that, I am even passing that right before the toast code line and still gives me the wrong value.

Comment: @BrianRoach - I have to admit. you were right, I passed the values, but I forgot one line where I pass the wrong number. Thanks and sorry everyone for not checking more before I ask.

Comment: you tried doing the calculations before displaying the result? like doing int result = (...calcualtions) and then diplaying the toast?

Comment: @GreatDreams:) It happens. Just always remember the [First Rule of Programming - It's always your fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html) (Great blog from Jeff Atwood, co-founder of StackOverflow)

Comment: Let me guess: ((15 + 1000) * 10) + 4000  (i.e. second number turned out to be 1000 rather than 100)

Comment: @John - Thanks for your quick response, I also learned from you that I can just use "+ instead of String.valueOf

Comment: @BrianRoach - Great blog indeed.

Comment: @CoreyKosak - you got that right. and le me guess it happend to you before or to someone you corrected :) just kidding.